# Ring homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a map $\alpha : F[x] \to L$ , where $L$ is $F[x]/(x^2+2x-1)$ and $F[x]$ is $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$, and what it does is $x \to t$, where $t$ is a square root of $2$ in $L$.

I need to prove it is a ring homomorphism. For that, I need to show first that $\alpha(1)=$ identity of $L$, then that $\alpha(a+b) = \alpha(a) + \alpha(b)$ and finally that $\alpha(ab) = \alpha(a)\cdot\alpha(b)$.

Also, I have found that $t = x+1$ in $L$.

How do I show those things? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not so much that you show that those relationships hold. Rather, you use them in order to define the map $\alpha$. You know the image of a single element. Now you define the image of the identity in $F[x]$ to be $1_L$, the identity of $L$, and define the image of a constant term $k$ to be $k \cdot 1_L$;
define the image of $k x^i$, for $k \in \mathbb{Z}/5$, to be $k t^i$, and the image of a sum to be the sum of the images. That's how you extend the given $x \mapsto t$ to a whole map $F[x] \to L$.

Now the properties you mention follow essentially because that's how $\alpha$ was defined.